# Vertical centering a container of text not working with margin auto

Tags: html, css

So I want to have a block of text centered next to an image, and I tried to use `margin auto 0px;` but it nothing. I also don't understand why the text starts at the bottom of the container instead of the top.

Here is the code:

```css
.feature {
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.feature img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}

.feature .feature-detail {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  margin: auto 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/Soylent.svg/800px-Soylent.svg.png">
  <div class="feature-detail">
    <h3>Feature Title</h3>
    <p>Feature Description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you made all direct children of `.feature` have `display: inline-block;` a simple `vertical-align: middle;` (on both the image and `.feature-detail`) will suffice.

```css
.feature {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.feature > * {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/Soylent.svg/800px-Soylent.svg.png">
  <div class="feature-detail">
    <h3>Feature Title</h3>
    <p>Feature Description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `vertical-align: middle;` in image css image css.

and  `display: flex;` & `align-items:center;` in `.feature` class

```css
.feature {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.feature img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.feature .feature-detail {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  margin: auto 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature">

  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/Soylent.svg/800px-Soylent.svg.png">

  <div class="feature-detail">
    <h3>Feature Title</h3>
    <p>Feature Description</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Does not look centered to me.

Comment: Thanks @connexo changed code with `feature` class. added `display: flex;` with  `align-items: center;`

Answer (score 0):

no need to use `display: inline-block;` `vertical-align:middle;` and `margin:auto 0px;` for `img` and `.feature-detail` class check updated css:

```css
.feature {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.feature img {
  width: 49%;
}

.feature .feature-detail {
  width: 49%;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature">

  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/Soylent.svg/800px-Soylent.svg.png">

  <div class="feature-detail">
    <h3>Feature Title</h3>
    <p>Feature Description</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), you can simplify your CSS.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.feature {
  margin: 5px 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Vertical alignment */
}

.feature img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/Soylent.svg/800px-Soylent.svg.png">
  <div class="feature-detail">
    <h3>Feature Title</h3>
    <p>Feature Description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```